# update sh file using VBA before perl script is run

Tags: vba, perl, shell

I have a VBA that creates a new directory folder and creates a new text file in that directory. I am trying to run a `perl` script from the VBA and have created a batch file that gets called from the VBA. That bat file uses a shell file to run a script. The directory in the script is dynamic and changes each time based on user input. My question is can the .sh file be updated before it is run?  I apologize for the long post, just wanted to be complete.  Thank you :).

**VBA**

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim MyBarCode   As String      ' Enter Barcode
Dim MyScan      As String      ' Enter ScanDate
Dim MyDirectory As String

MyBarCode = Application.InputBox("Please enter the barcode", "Bar Code", Type:=2)
If MyBarCode = "False" Then Exit Sub   'user canceled
Do
    MyScan = Application.InputBox("Please enter scan date", "Scan Date", Date, Type:=2)
    If MyScan = "False" Then Exit Sub   'user canceled
    If IsDate(MyScan) Then Exit Do
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid date format. ", vbExclamation, "Invalid Date Entry"
Loop

Range("B20").Value = MyBarCode
Range("B21").Value = CDate(MyScan)

MyDirectory = "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\" & MyBarCode & "_" & Format(CDate(MyScan), "m-d-yyyy") & "\"
' Create nexus directory and folder
If Dir(MyDirectory, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir MyDirectory

If MsgBox("The project file has been created. " & _
          "Do you want to create a template for analysis now?", _
          vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

    'Write to text file
    Open MyDirectory & "sample_descriptor.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, "Experiment Sample" & vbTab & "Control Sample" & vbTab & "Display Name" & vbTab & "Gender" & vbTab & "Control Gender" & vbTab & "SpikeIn Location"
    Print #1, MyBarCode & "_532Block1.txt" & vbTab & MyBarCode & "_635Block1.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("B9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B12").Value
    Print #1, MyBarCode & "_532Block2.txt" & vbTab & MyBarCode & "_635Block2.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("C9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C11").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C12").Value
    Print #1, MyBarCode & "_532Block3.txt" & vbTab & MyBarCode & "_635Block3.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("D9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D11").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D12").Value
    Print #1, MyBarCode & "_532Block4.txt" & vbTab & MyBarCode & "_635Block4.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E11").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E12").Value
    Close #1

    'Run ImaGene
    If MsgBox("Please run the ImaGene analysis. " & _
          "and click yes after it completes to verify the spike-ins.", _
          vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

    **'Update folder structure and call .bat
    Dim PathCrnt As String
    Dim FN As Long

    FN = FreeFile 'FreeFile gets an available file number'
    Open "C:\cygwin\home\cmccabe\Run_probes.sh" For Output As FN

    PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    *system.diagnostics.process.Start ("C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat") & PathCrnt*
    Close FN
    End If**
End Sub

Else
    MsgBox "Nothing has been done. ", vbExclamation, "Goodbye!"
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Quit

End Sub
```

**Bat with that calls `perl` script:**

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -i ./Run_probes.sh
```

**Run_probes.sh**

```
perl "C:\cygwin\home\cmccabe\get_imagene_spikein_probe_values.pl" "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\*257168310045_8-18-2015*" "ImaGene EmArray- Template.txt" < test_probes8.txt > "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\*257168310045_8-18-2015*\output.txt"
```

Comment: Why call `bash` at all? You can invoke Perl instead, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice post! Very detailed. :)

Certainly the Perl file can be updated before it is run. Just write the update path into the file like you write the data into sample_descriptor.txt. eg:

```
Dim FN as Long
FN = FreeFile 'FreeFile gets an available file number'
Open PathToShFile For Output As FN
Print FN, "perl " & chr(34) & PathCrnt & _
  & chr(34) & "\get_imagene_spikein_probe_values.pl" & chr(34) &  _
  & chr(34) & "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\*257168310045_8-18-2015*" & _
  chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & _
  " ImaGene EmArray- Template.txt" & chr(34) & _ 
  " < test_probes8.txt > " & chr(34) & _
  "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\*257168310045_8-18-2015*\output.txt"  & chr(34)
Close FN
```

I'm not sure I got all the `"` marks replaced with `chr(34)` correctly so make sure to echo out that string before trying to execute any code. You might also make it more readable (and configurable) by using variables to store paths. eg:

`strNPath = "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\*257168310045_8-18-2015*\"`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and I am glad the details helped, it is much appreciated :)

Comment: I thought I understood, but I edited the code and not sure it looks right.  Thank you :).

Comment: For clarity, try assigning all your paths to variables (like I did with strNPath). Then find the path you want changed and see if it is correct. If not and if you can't figure out  how to get it corrected, post the value of that variable and what it should be (generally, since its dynamic).

Comment: Also, if you can optionally use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` in your bi long perl line, use them Its more readable than all my chr(34) changes and less confusing than trying to use 2 or 3 double quotes to escape. (its been a few years since I did any Perl coding so I don't remember...sorry)

Comment: I made the change in the 'Update folder structure and call .bat section. I am getting a bad file name with the strNPath highlighted.  Thank you:).

Comment: Ahh! I see. Yes, you are setting a folder path but not actually specifying a file: `strNPath = "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\*257168310045_8-18-2015*\"` is just the path to the file, but does not specify the file so your `Open` statement must append the filename to strNPath. eg: `Open strNPath & "myfile.bat" For Output As FN` just use the name of the batch file in place of `myfile.bat`

Comment: I added the file to open but am getting a bad file/path name and that is highlighted.  Thank you :).

Comment: You might want to brush up on the differences between drives, folders, and files. Your Open statement is trying to open `N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\*257168310045_8-18-2015*\C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat`. It is not possible to name a folder `C:` in any OS afaik. I don't know which file you really want to open at that point...one on your N drive or one on your C drive, but you certainly can't use both drives in that statement. :) I recommended using variables for the folders to improve readability and configurability, however it isn't 100% necessary.

Comment: I mis-read your post and corrected it in the edit but am getting a Object Required error in the system.diagnostics.... (the part that calls the bat file).  Thank you :).

Comment: system.diagnostics.process.Start isn't a VBA command. Any reason why you switched from using `call Shell`?

Comment: when I use `Call Shell(PathCrnt & "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat " & PathCrnt)` I get file not found, so I read that system.diagnostics may help.  It appears I was wrong though.   Thank you :).

Comment: Yeah, `PathCrnt` appears to contain the path to the workbook...probably something like `C:\Users\cmcabe\Documents\ `.  So when you concatenate them with the code `PathCrnt & "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat " & PathCrnt` you are telling Windows/VBA to open `C:\Users\cmcabe\Documents\C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat C:\Users\cmcabe\Documents\ ` You've got this once you figure your paths (Drive\folder\folder\file) out.

Comment: Thanks Tim I am going to change the code to: `PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & MyBarCode & "_" & MyScan
        Call Shell("C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat ")` and go from there: hopefully that will use the Activeworkbook.Path and call the bat file on the C drive.